# useRef variable inside useEffect with requestAnimationFrame and cancelAnimationFrame

Tags: react-native, use-effect, use-ref

in my react native app I run a loop of animations with:

```
let rafId = useRef(null);

const loop () => {
      ...do something...
};
    
rafId.current = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

In my useEffect when the component will be unmounted I want to stop the last animation.

Is it correct like this?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (rafId.current != null && rafId.current !== 0) 
      {
        cancelAnimationFrame(rafId.current); 
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's correct, but why do you need the !==0 assertion ?
I think if (rafId.current) cancelAnimationFrame(rafId.current); is enough.

Comment: Thank you Cesare. Yes I could change and check only rafId.current.